# How to upload data in model through migrations in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django. I made a new model named suggestion_title which has two fields named fa_id , desc. And i have data in the form of text to filled in that. So is there any way to upload data by migration or something. I don't want to add data manually. I heard about fixture but could not able to find the good solution. please help.

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of Django you can use fixtures, but for versions >= 1.7, the preferred way to go is a Data Migration:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models, migrations

def create_objects(apps, schema_editor):
    SuggestionTitle.objects.create(fa_id="foo", desc="bar")

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_objects),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a fixture, not a migration. Fixtures can be in JSON, XML, or YAML format. The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/) explains how to use fixtures.

In your case, a JSON fixture might look like:

```
[
  {
    "model": "YOURAPPNAME.suggestion_title",
    "fields": {
      "fa_id": "FOO",
      "desc": "BAR"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "YOURAPPNAME.suggestion_title",
    "fields": {
      "fa_id": "BAZ",
      "desc": "QUX"
    }
  }
]
```

Once you create your fixture, you load it using the `loaddata` management command, e.g:

`manage.py loaddata myfixture.json`

Comment: This solution is deprecated since Django 1.7

Comment: @Joseph See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures for more info.

Comment: m using Django 1.7 , so u are saying to create a fixture file and simply run the following command : python manage.py myfixture.json ?? 
Right?? Is this will fill the data in my tables?

Comment: My understanding wasn't that OP was looking for automatic loading of fixtures, and it is that specific feature that is deprecated. The `loaddata` command itself isn't deprecated. An initial fixture to be imported manually with `loaddata` is an absolutely valid solution. 

@NewPie, yes, create your fixture file. You'll need to take the records you have and convert them to JSON like I showed. Once you have that file, you can import it with loaddata.